# Get result from modulo operation in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I want to achieve following result in **iOS Swift 3** as per screenshot of googling. PFA below
[image]

I try in **iOS Swift 3** but stuck when doing this, see the code

```
let resultAfterModulo: Int = (-3) % 24
print(resultAfterModulo)
```

output:
**-3**

but output should be **21**

Could anyone help me in this..?? Thanks in advance....

Comment: @Martin R thanks alot....